# convert reponse of jquery ajax call (need to handle 404 error for gravtar) for getting gravatar into image source

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, gravatar

Here's my code:

```
var hashEmail = md5.createHash(email);

$.get("http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/" + hashEmail + "?d=404")
                        .then(function(response) {
                            var data = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + response;
                            $('.result').html('<img src="' + data + '" class="img-circle"/><span class="username username-hide-mobile" ng-bind="'+ attributes.name +'"></span>'); 
                        }, function(response) {
                           return defaultProfileImage();
                        });
```

The response which I'm getting is as follows:

**

�����%10JFIF�%01%01��%01�%01�����;CREATOR: gd-jpeg v1.0 (using IJG JPEG v80), quality = 90���C�%03%02%02%03%02%02%03%03%03%03%04%03%03%04%05%08%05%05%04%04%05%07%07%06%08%0C%0C%0C%0B%0B%0B%0E%12%10%0E%11%0E%0B%0B%10%16%10%11%13%14%15%15%15%0C%0F%17%18%16%14%18%12%14%15%14���C%01%03%04%04%05%04%05%05%05%14%0B%14%14%14%14%14%14%14%14%14%14%14%14%14%14%14%14%14%14%14%14%14%14%14%14%14%14%14%14%14%14%14%14%14%14%14%14%14%14%14%14%14%14%14%14%14%14%14%14%14%14���%11%08�P�P

**

I'm unable to convert this response into an image source. Am I doing anything wrong? Here's what I have already tried :

> // var binaryData = [];
>
> // binaryData.push(response);
>
> // var img = new window.Image();
>
> // img.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(response);
>
> // scope.imageUrl = img.src;
>
> // scope.imageUrl = (window.URL || window.webkitURL).createObjectURL(img);
>
> // scope.imageUrl = window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(response)));
>
> // let blob = new Blob([response], { type: 'image/jpeg' });
>
> // scope.imageUrl = (window.URL || window.webkitURL).createObjectURL(blob);
>
> // scope.imageUrl = response;
>
> // return scope.imageUrl;

Also tried with angular $http service call but was getting CORS issue so someone suggested to go with Jquery Ajax call

Comment: Why would you use ajax to get an image at all, just insert the url directly.

Comment: to handle error response so that if gravatar doenot exist (instead of their default gravatar icon) do something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve this kind of issue by using FileReader API together with XMLHttpRequest

```
var hashEmail = md5.createHash(email);

toImageUri('https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/' + hashEmail + '?d=404', function(imgDataUri){
             $('.result').html('<img src="' + imgDataUri + '" class="img-circle"/>'); 
    });

    function toImageUri(url, callback){
       var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
           xhr.responseType = 'blob';
           xhr.onload = function() {
               var reader  = new FileReader();
               reader.onloadend = function () {
               callback(reader.result);
           }
              reader.readAsDataURL(xhr.response);
          };
            xhr.open('GET', url);
            xhr.send();
    }
```

If you really need a pure jQuery solution take a look at this link https://github.com/acigna/jquery-ajax-native